# Getting error while installing "azure-powershell.0.8.7.msi" through .cmd file

Tags: powershell, azure, windows-installer, startup

I am trying to install “azure-powershell.0.8.7.msi” through a .cmd file using command
msiexec.exe /i ".\azure-powershell.0.8.7.MSI" /passive

This msi file is part of solution explorer(part of project, I have to do it in this way only). 
Although I am able to install/uninstall when this msi file when it’s on local disk ( i.e. on some drive)

I tried to log the error it is:
“This installation package could not be opened.  Verify that the package exists and that you can access it, or contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package.”

It is a known error of Microsoft. I tried each and every proposed solution on internet but it doesn’t work.
Note: The current user/admin of the system have all the access(read,write,modify).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your MSI-file is in the same directory like the cmd-file you have to us the following command

`msiexec /i "%~dp0azure-powershell.0.8.7.MSI" /qb`

%~dp0 is refering to cmd-file directory and in this case to the MSI-file. 
If you want to create a log-file use the `/l` and the logfilepath plus name after `/qb`.
For example:

`msiexec /i "%~dp0azure-powershell.0.8.7.MSI" /qb /l*v %temp%\azure-powershell.log`

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel Michen.
One problem I am facing now, I am installing this msi file in through "Start up" task of a worker role in Azure, and than executing my Powershell commands(.ps1) file in Run() method of Worker role.
It is not working, but Since the msi has been installed and I run my code again with "Start up" task commented , powershell script work fine.